# Milestones not working when case created from test code

Tags: api, entitlements, casemilestone

I have an Entitlement process and support triggers that I would like to test so that I can submit code into product.

Problem:

When I create all the object through code I only get one of the Milestones out of three that I am expecting (First Response).

When I take the code out of test so that I can see what object are created I get the same result.  However when I create a case manually using the objects created from the code (out of test) I get the three Milestones that I am expecting to be created for the case.

The two Milestones I am not seeing have a Start Time of "Entitlement Process", they are:

```
Restore SLA Case Priority equals Critical (1) AND Restore Point equals null
```

and

```
Resolve SLA Case Priority equals Critical (1) AND Closed not equal to True
```

(and the above with Priority High, Medium/Low).

Finding that if I let the "Priority" default (to low) I am seeing the Milestones I expect.

I am using the following to set Priority:

newCase.Priority = 'Critical (4)';

In the case created from code it is setting the priority correctly but not setting up Milestones as it should.

Answer (score 1):

I confess I've never worked with Milestones. But if I understand correctly some kind of best match is being used *(perhaps the first match if they're somehow ordered? Like in approval processes - you can have multiple approvals on 1 object, you need to set them in order and the first one that matches entry criteria is being used)*.

[This help article](http://eu1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/entitlements_about.htm) says:

> Salesforce assigns milestones with matching criteria to the case. For
>   example, if a milestone's criteria is Priority equals High, and a case
>   has a Priority of High, Salesforce assigns it to the Priority equals
>   High milestone.
>
> **A case associates with one milestone at a time**; it can associate with many milestones as it moves through the process.

I suspect you'll have to change values and update your Case record (maybe even more than once; or maybe you need more than 1 test record) to see it progressing through Milestones.

Answer (score 1):

Well when you are creating case from the standard page I guess you are explicitly selecting value for "Entitlement Name" or "EntitlementId"(Api Name). While creating the same from code you have set the Entitlement Id by doing something like : 



`Case.EntitlementId  = [SELECT Id,Name FROM Entitlement WHERE Name = 'My Entitlement'].Id`

Answer (score 1):

Priority setting problem:

newCase.Priority = 'Critical (4)';

Should be:

newCase.Priority = 'Critical (1)';

Surprised that some sort of error did not occur. It is always the little things. :)